# Include template with variable depending on locale of user

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to include template depending on locale of user.
This is the static code and it works fine

```
{% include 'AppBundle:Frontend:content_en.html.twig' %}
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
{% include {{ 'AppBundle:Frontend:content_' ~ app.request.locale ~ '.html.twig'  }} %}
```

This is the error

```
A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses 
(unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in AppBundle:Frontend:index.html.twig at line 18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

```
{{ include ('AppBundle:Frontend:content_' ~ app.request.locale ~ '.html.twig')  }}
```